# Application_Error is not catching 404 type of error

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'd like to catch these types of error globally so that I can log them to the database and display a nice message to the user: 500, 403, and 404. I'm using **Log4Net** to handle the error.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
  string redirectUrl = "~/Error/GenericError.aspx"; //I put a breakpoint here...
  var httpException = (HttpException)Server.GetLastError();
  int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();

  //more code here...
}
```

The breakpoint is being hit only when an exception happens, then the error is recognized as 500.

However, when I misspell a **URL**, I except a 404 error to be caught by the **Application_Error** method. Instead, I the browser displays this page (see screenshot). There's no way to log the error in that case.

I'm **ASP.NET Webform 4.5**. In the previous version, such as **ASP.NET 4.0**, I was able to catch all 3 types of errors.

Is there a way to catch the 404 error as well?

Comment: Do you have any configuration in your web.config@sytem.web\customErrors section?

Comment: There's not `CustomError` or anything related to `error` in the System.web section.

Answer (score 0):

By "Misspell url" I assume you mean the controller/action portion of the url (vs the domain or subdomain), other wise this would be a moot question. If so, then like K.Tamayo mentioned check that customerrors is off as follows:

`<configuration>`
`<system.web>`
`<customErrors mode="Off"/>`
`</system.web>`
`</configuration>`

Comment: Theres nothing related to `customErrors` in the entire config file. I've all the way to the end of the file a section that I defined myself for `log4net`. By mispelling, I mean: Instead of `customers/Dashboard`, I write `customers/Dashboard__XX`. Also, it's not a `MVC` but a `webform 4.5`.

Comment: Asp.Net Pipeline should work the same for all, as does web.config.  Go ahead and add the previously noted customerrors tag in the system.web section of your web.config.   Once you have done this, I would suggest running in VS debug mode with break points in the Application_Error method.

Comment: Also, you can get detailed info about the http request by adding other standard pipeline event methods into your Global.asax.  For example, you could add "protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {//your commands go here; anything will do that you can set a break point on}.  This is an ok reference link for pipeline:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441421/httpmodule-event-execution-order

Comment: I've added the customErrors section and put a breakpoint in the Application_Error method, with not success.

Comment: I've added the Application_BeginRequest and put a break point. The breakpoint is being hit, which is a good new. Then how do I know that the request failed and that the error is 404?

Comment: It seems like `PreRequestHandlerExecute` is the last handler that is being hit when the error is `404`

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the 404 page from web.config as below

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" >
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="404.aspx?/>
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>
</configuration
```

Inside the 404.aspx, you can log the error and display whatever you want.

I am not sure why the Application_Error is not being fired, but I believe it is supposed to work when there is a server side exception happened, but according to the answer of this question, it should work

[Best way to implement a 404 in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667053/best-way-to-implement-a-404-in-asp-net)

Comment: I've added the above code to the config file, but I'm still not being redirected to 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the request managed by the framework itself. So it doesn't hit *Application_Error*

If you want to catch all the errors in *Application_Error* add below in **web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Find below thread for the detailed response.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258217/7013033