# Serve files dynamically instead of statically

Tags: c#, caching, visual-studio-2015, browser-cache, asp.net-routing

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6453724/1680677), I've enabled serving JavaScript and CSS from my Views folder which is helping my project's organization. Unfortunately, while I'm developing, I find I have to disable my browser cache in order to see my changes. I'd like to be able to develop without keeping DevTools open just to disable the cache.

I figure my issue is the `System.Web.StaticFileHandler` serving up the files in such a way that the browser caches them. I've tried using `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11258217/1680677) suggests, but then I get 500 Server Errors instead.

Is my understanding of the problem correct? How can I resolve my issue?

Note: Not that it's relevant, but I intend to add a config transform to switch back to the static handler for releases.

Comment: the cached version is used if the file is not changed. This is expected. Can you tell us why you don't want this behavior

Comment: I'm actively developing (and saving) and in the browser I'm seeing old versions of the files I'm working on even when I refresh.